# RETURN FRAGMENT IN TAB HOST ANDROID

Tags: android, fragment, android-tabhost

```
 public Fragment getItem(int num) {
            switch (num)
            {
                case 0:
                    NewFragment fragment = new NewFragment();
                    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                    prepareNew();
                    bundle.putParcelableArrayList("arrPost",arrPost);
                    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                    return fragment;
                case 1:
                    return null;
                case 2:
                    return null;
                default:
                    return null;

            }

        }
```

IN CASE 0: IS IT WRONG ?, I PUT DEBUG ON LINE (1->6 FROM CASE 0:), BUT NOT ARCHIVE TO LINE 6 ? ANY IDEA, PLEASE HELP ME

Comment: Please don't use all caps

Comment: Using all caps is considered SHOUTING on the inter-webs by most; please edit.

Comment: Its not clear what your error is, but I'm guessing you've imported the wrong Fragment class.